# Display list files and folder using Mediafire API

Tags: api

I tryed to use [Mediafire API](http://developers.mediafire.com/index.php/REST_API), but when I use Folder, get_info, it doesn't return file & folder array like the example.

Full url I used: http://www.mediafire.com/api/folder/get_info.php?folder_key=l461cm2d8hfxd

What's wrong with my attempt? Thank you.

Comment: `get_content` with `content_type=files` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just took a look at their API documentation. They've updated the get_info function for the folders. They've taken out the file tree....

So if you are uploading via the dropbox (which doesn't return the quickkey associated with the file), you CAN NEVER dropbox upload and then use the api to find the file and download it. This renders their API as useless as tits on a boar hog.

The point of a dropbox is to allow remote uploads to a folder, you then know the folder key so you can query the API and return the document quickkeys that are in the folder which then allows you to manage those files remotely, move, delete, download etc. Now you cannot do this FAIL FAIL FAIL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [MediaFire API PHP Library](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7598-PHP-Upload-and-retrieve-files-to-MediaFire-service.html). This class currently implements all the functions in the Mediafire API.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the Functionality of get_info not working, folder search can resolve at least some issues with retrieving quick keys. In my case i searched for ".mp3" and was handed all the mp3s in my folder